# Linking OpenVR through VCPKG via CMAKE

Tags: cmake, vcpkg, openvr

I have Installed OpenVR through vcpkg and am trying to link it via CMAKE, the issue is that I don't know how to do it, nor can I find any info on how to.

Unlike other packages where once installed it tells you how to link via CMAKE by using find_package and target_link_libraries, OpenVR doesn't. I initially assumed that

```
find_package(openvr CONFIG REQUIRED) 
target_link_libraries(${Proj_Name} PRIVATE openvr::openvr)
```

would work but instead I get the error

```
CMake Error at C:/dev/vcpkg/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:793 (_find_package):
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "openvr" with any
of the following names:

openvrConfig.cmake
openvr-config.cmake

Add the installation prefix of "openvr" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
"openvr_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "openvr"
provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
installed.
```

Usually vcpkg.cmake provides CMAKE with the config.cmake files but not for OpenVR, so how do i link it properly?

Comment: When you run `vcpkg install openvr`, it should give you usage instructions... what does it say?

Comment: @AlexReinking it doesn't say anything, which is weird as SDL2, glm, glfw3 and the other packages I installed all gave usage instructions

Comment: _Definitely_ look for an issue on the vcpkg GitHub issue tracker. If one doesn't exist, open an issue. https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a find module that seems to work. OpenVR does some very non-standard things with its debug library naming. I tested this on Linux, and it works, but I do not have easy access to a Windows machine right now. Let me see the error message if it fails and I can try to fix it.

You'll use it like this, from the top-level CMakeLists.txt

```
# ./CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project(test)

list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")

find_package(OpenVR REQUIRED)

add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE OpenVR::OpenVR)
```

And then just put the following find module in `cmake/FindOpenVR.cmake`:

```
# cmake/FindOpenVR.cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)

function(_OpenVR_find)
  include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)
  include(SelectLibraryConfigurations)

  ## Find the include path
  find_path(OpenVR_INCLUDE_DIR NAMES openvr.h)

  ## Determine version by scanning header
  if (OpenVR_INCLUDE_DIR)
    set(openvr_header "${OpenVR_INCLUDE_DIR}/openvr.h")

    set(re_major "^\tstatic const uint32_t k_nSteamVRVersionMajor = ([0-9]+).*;$")
    set(re_minor "^\tstatic const uint32_t k_nSteamVRVersionMinor = ([0-9]+).*;$")
    set(re_patch "^\tstatic const uint32_t k_nSteamVRVersionBuild = ([0-9]+).*;$")

    file(STRINGS "${openvr_header}" OpenVR_VERSION_MAJOR REGEX "${re_major}")
    file(STRINGS "${openvr_header}" OpenVR_VERSION_MINOR REGEX "${re_minor}")
    file(STRINGS "${openvr_header}" OpenVR_VERSION_PATCH REGEX "${re_patch}")

    string(REGEX REPLACE "${re_major}" "\\1"
           OpenVR_VERSION_MAJOR "${OpenVR_VERSION_MAJOR}")
    string(REGEX REPLACE "${re_minor}" "\\1"
           OpenVR_VERSION_MINOR "${OpenVR_VERSION_MINOR}")
    string(REGEX REPLACE "${re_patch}" "\\1"
           OpenVR_VERSION_PATCH "${OpenVR_VERSION_PATCH}")

    if (OpenVR_VERSION_MAJOR AND OpenVR_VERSION_MINOR AND OpenVR_VERSION_PATCH)
      set(OpenVR_VERSION
          "${OpenVR_VERSION_MAJOR}.${OpenVR_VERSION_MINOR}.${OpenVR_VERSION_PATCH}")
    endif ()
  endif ()

  ## Find the library
  find_library(OpenVR_LIBRARY_RELEASE NAMES openvr_api)

  # OpenVR uses a highly non-standard additional suffix to mark debug libraries
  list(TRANSFORM CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES APPEND ".dbg")
  find_library(OpenVR_LIBRARY_DEBUG NAMES openvr_api)

  select_library_configurations(OpenVR)

  ## Perform all the standard required, version, etc. argument checks.
  find_package_handle_standard_args(
    OpenVR
    REQUIRED_VARS OpenVR_LIBRARY OpenVR_INCLUDE_DIR
    VERSION_VAR OpenVR_VERSION
    HANDLE_VERSION_RANGE
    HANDLE_COMPONENTS
  )

  ## Create OpenVR::OpenVR imported target.
  if (OpenVR_FOUND AND NOT OpenVR::OpenVR)
    add_library(OpenVR::OpenVR UNKNOWN IMPORTED)
    target_include_directories(OpenVR::OpenVR INTERFACE "${OpenVR_INCLUDE_DIR}")
    set_target_properties(
      OpenVR::OpenVR PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION "${OpenVR_LIBRARY}"
    )

    foreach (cfg IN ITEMS RELEASE DEBUG)
      if (OpenVR_LIBRARY_${cfg})
        set_property(
          TARGET OpenVR::OpenVR APPEND PROPERTY IMPORTED_CONFIGURATIONS ${cfg}
        )
        set_target_properties(
          OpenVR::OpenVR PROPERTIES
          IMPORTED_LOCATION_${cfg} "${OpenVR_LIBRARY_${cfg}}"
        )
      endif ()
    endforeach ()
  endif ()

  ## Export whitelisted variables
  set(OpenVR_FOUND "${OpenVR_FOUND}" PARENT_SCOPE)
  set(OpenVR_VERSION "${OpenVR_VERSION}" PARENT_SCOPE)
endfunction()

_OpenVR_find()

function(_OpenVR_find)
endfunction()

function(_OpenVR_find)
endfunction()
```

Comment: Thanks for the assistance, this solved my problems

Comment: Happy to help and welcome to StackOverflow!